# Howe energy is exchanged in vortex tubes?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

In ***vortex tubes***, energy is transferred from some particles (which will be pushed to the centre (how?) and form the cold stream) to some other particles (peripheral particles, which will form the hot stream).

How this energy exchange happens? what is the mechanism? and why this energy is received as internal energy (higher temperature) and not kinetic energy (higher translational speed or any other type of energy)?

Comment: The air comes in at one pressure but in   swirling the pressure is lower at the centre and higher at the periphery. The center gas must have expanded, and so has done work and  cooled, while the gas  at the periphery has been compressed and  so has had work done on it and therefore has got  hotter.